# .metadata\.log error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a problem with Eclipse, it worked until yesterday, and now when i try to open it, i get this message 
[ an error has occurred see the log file workspacename.metadata.log] 
i searched i found some Suggestions like delete some files on .metadata.plugins but not working with me !
so any help

```
eclipse.buildId=v21.1.0-569685
java.version=1.7.0_10
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=ar_SA
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this problem by follow this step:

1-delete metadata folder (workspace)
2-reinstall java JDK
3 re unzip eclipse

Answer (score 9):

Delete: /YOUR PATH TO WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources

**Update 2018**
I do not recommend this answer anymore. I was tested it 2014 and it was working for me for older eclipse IDE at that time. I m not using eclipse anymore for development. I recommended using an android studio for android development. Thank you

Comment: if someone put -1 to the answer .. its better to say the reason too

Comment: It was not enough (at least for me); you need to delete whole ./metadata folder, as mentioned by other answers

Comment: Deleting .metadata folder will never be good option, if you number of  projects and any configurations, all will be lost.

Answer (score 5):

1) You have to delete the folder `metadata` in your workspace.

2) Start Eclipse as usual - the folder `metadata` is newly creating by starting Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

If your operation system is Mac OS and you are using version of Java 1.9 this error occurs and eclipse don't start up. 
So you need to downgrade your java version to 1.8 release until this issue fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to delete the folder metadata in your workspace. is the best way to resolved this issue. solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I added `-clean` in the top of **eclipse.ini** file and it works for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well and is a less invasive change than deleting all metadata.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while opening eclipse because of incompatible jdk version with eclipse.
I use eclipse eclipse LUNA and i downloaded jdk10.1 version which eclipse luna cannot handle,it can handle only jdk8 or below versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the **snap** file located under metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/

That might fix it.

Comment: I've done this a time or two before and it worked.  I believe this answer is for when your box was forcefully reloaded leaving eclipse in a bad state because it wasn't closed out.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 64 OS user here. I solved this problem by installing the latest JDK, as of now jdk-8u302-windows-x64.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubunut 20.04 
I have JDK 11 and JDK 8 installed, and I downloaded Eclipse Luna
By defaul JDK 11 was installed. I tried to install Eclipse but didn't work.

I changed the version by JDK 8 using:

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Pulse intro to select the version according to the numbers that come out:
example: 0,1, etc 
Again I installed and it worked with JDK8.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the error because the policy had some compliance changes and it seemed to me the JDK installed became unstable or incomplete. So, I reinstalled JDK 17 (on top of the same existing folder), then this error was resolved and Eclipse 2023-12 started successfully.

Answer (score -1):

Well, my suggestion is you follow the instructions and actually see the log file workspacename.metadata.log. If you already did, attach the relevant stack trace so we can help.

Comment: oh, i was delete this file !! i try to open eclipse again than i get this message [ cant open myprojectname\lib\jvm.cfg ] !!

Answer (score -1):

I have tried every solution from stackoverflow, youtube even i have reinstalled OS etc. but still it as showing same error.Downgrading JDK 1.9 to JDK 1.8 worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

If you recently updated your java version, most likely eclipse is trying to use the new version unless explicitly specified. Just explicitly specify the jdk you were using before.

If using a MAC the steps will look as follow for example:

```
ECLIPSE FOLDER/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini.
```

Add the following

```
-vm
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/OLDER_JDK/Contents/Home/bin
```

For me OLDER_JDK was jdk1.8.0_144.jdk

Answer (score -1):

Deleting workspace/.metadata will remove all your downloaded plugins and libraries which I do not recommend. The best and easy solution is to change your JAVA_HOME path. If you are using multiple JDKs then change the JAVA_HOME path to the one which you have used in Eclipse recently. You can check the Java version using the command **java -version**.

Answer (score -2):

Delete .metadata folder or follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7qOGSYcw8Y https://mauricemutetingundi.blogspot.com/2019/03/problem-solved-error-has-occurred-see.html then start eclipse. If the the projects are lost on eclipse sidebar load them again by clicking file menu and selecting appropriate options

Comment: In order to be immediately helpful to readers (and avoid [Linkrot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot)), we prefer answer that provide at least a solid summary of the solution directly, with links used to offer additional information. [More info on link only answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).