# how to recover Pydev in Eclipse after errasing metadata file?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

This morning I turned on the computer to find that Eclipse would not open up. The error message was "an error has occurred see the log file workspacename.metadata.log". I did look at this file and could not understand what was wrong :(

Guided by one of the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379438/metadata-log-error-in-eclipse) I erased all the metadata folder in that project. This is a pydev project.
Now Eclipse opens fine but the pydev perspective and everything that goes with it is gone for this project and I don't know how to recover it. I was able to go to open a different project and pydev is fine in there, but somehow it is missing in my current project.

Any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: well, I think I figured it out:
I first went to "Window -> open perspective -> other" and selected Pydev. Then I went to File -> import workspace -> and imported my old workspace. I think this will make it. I do not answer my question myself bc I think this might not be the most elegant solution...

Comment: Thanks @nicain for giving me (via personal communication) the idea of how to solve this issue!