# Eclipse Neon will not run

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-neon

I click on eclipse.exe and a box comes up that says "An error has occurred: see the log file C:\Users\sam\workspace\.metadata\.log". I searched on this error message and found lots of people with the same issue (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379438/metadata-log-error-in-eclipse), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042824/not-able-to-run-eclipse-application-cant-even-start-eclipse-ide), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15333825/an-error-has-occured-please-see-log-file-eclipse-juno), and lots of others) but none of the solutions in any answers worked for me, not even a change in the error message. I then searched on the specific error in the log file, which is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2019-06-27 12:56:35.009
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:426)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    ... 21 more
```

and found some other things that didn't work.

Here are some of the things I tried:

- Deleting and reinstalling Eclipse
- Going to the command line and running eclipse with `eclipse.exe -clean`, `eclipse.exe -clean --launcher.ini (path to eclipse.ini)`, and `eclipse.exe -clean --clearPersistedState` - None changed the outcome
- Deleting the entire .metadata folder, the entire workspace folder, and the contents of the .plugins folder.
- Altering the eclipse.ini file in various ways, including putting `.clean` at the top, replacing `-vmargs` with `-vm` and the path to `javaw.exe`. nothing worked, or even changed anything
- running eclipse as administrator (i.e. I am desperate)

I have Windows 10 64-bit, Eclipse Neon 3 64-bit, java is in my PATH, and this is what comes up when I type `java -version`:

```
java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13, mixed mode)
```

I hesitated to ask this question on SO, but I think something might have changed in the time since it was last asked. None of those solutions worked for me, and I have no other option at this point.

Comment: Eclipse Neon is too old to run with Java 10. Use the current Eclipse 2019-06 or go back to Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As was mentioned by greg-449 in a comment, you can't use Java 10 with Neon.

There's a [compatibility chart](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation) on the eclipse wiki that specifies what versions of Java are required for a given version of eclipse.

You'll notice that in the entry for Eclipse [4.6](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.6_.28Neon.29) (Neon) it specifies that **"A Java 8 JRE/JDK is required..."** as opposed to version [4.7](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Eclipse_4.7_.28Oxygen.29) and higher, which need **"A Java 8 or newer JRE/JDK..."**

This is further clarified in the [Install a JVM](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/Installation#Install_a_JVM) section, which has a warning that

> If using Java 9 or newer please use Eclipse 4.7.1a or newer as it contains fixes in Eclipse launcher to add all JVM modules.

Comment: thank you so much! I hadn't used eclipse in a while (I was using Android Studio) and since then I have updated my Java version so that explains it. It makes me wonder why they wouldn't put that anywhere in the error message...